# KRL: How to fire on all domains

Tags: krl

I have been working on a personal project for a few months. A large majority of my frustration stems from the fact that I am building my own extension from scratch. I am only half way done with the project, and I am nervous that getting the code to port to IE and Chrome won't be as easy as I hoped it would be.

I had initially wanted to use Kynetx for this project, however I was told that it wasn't possible to get your app to fire on all domains. In chatting with Mike Grace, he told me that it IS possible. Can someone explain how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the dispatch block you can set a domain of

```
.*
```

Which in a full ruleset looks like this

```
ruleset a60x554 {
  meta {
    name "all-domains-dispatch-test"
    description <<
      all-domains-dispatch-test
    >>
    author "Mike Grace"
    logging on
  }

  dispatch {
    domain ".*"
  }

  rule muahahaha {
    select when pageview ".*"
    {
      notify(": )","All your domain belong to us!") with sticky = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**I know this works with the Firefox and Chrome extensions but I have never tested it with an IE extension.**

Action shots!
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ha! I was SOO happy when I discovered this back in the day. +1. GREAT ANSWER! Your answers are always so awesomely detailed and awesome awesomeness.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This is great to have. I love the nintendo reference.

Comment: @aaronfrost You bet. Be sure to accept the answer if it successfully answers your question.